# Find coeffiecients $a,b$ for a given function f such that $f(t) \le at^2+bt$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $f:\left[0, \infty \right) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and differentiable function. We make the following assumptions:
>
> $f(0) = 0 $
>
> $f'(0) = -1$
>
> $\exists K > 0 \text{ such that } \left| f'(t_2)-f'(t_1)\right| \le K\left|t_2-t_1\right| (\forall t_2,t_1 > 0)$
>
> Find some coefficients $a>0$ and $b<0$ such that $f(t) \le at^2+bt \ \ (\forall t \ge 0)$

I think that the third assumption might be the key for this task, but I do not know how to use it on this. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Your title and question don't seem to match - are you trying to prove that $\left| f'(t_2)-f'(t_1)\right| \le K\left|t_2-t_1\right|$, or are you trying to find coefficients, or are you trying to show such coefficients exist?

Comment: I'm sorry I'll edit the title

Comment: @B.Mehta: I am trying to find such coefficients $a,b$.

Comment: Hint: $f'(t) - f'(0) \le Kt \implies f(t) = f(0) + \int_0^t f'(\tau)d\tau \le \cdots$

Comment: @achille hui: You mean: $f(t) = f(0) + \int_0^t f'(\tau)d\tau \le f(0) + Kt$ ?

Comment: Nope, I mean $\int_0^t f'(\tau)d\tau \le \int_0^t (-1+K\tau)d\tau = -t + \frac{K}{2}t^2$.